# Html and php form not submitting issue

Tags: javascript, php, html

Hi guys I have been having trouble with one of the websites using HTML and PHP

The form doesn't seem to submit or send a message. Attached is the code please any help will be great. Also, the PHP and javascript have been attached for reference.
Also sometimes the page doesn't respond to the button.
If anyone can fix the code will be great.

```js
CONTACT FORM
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

function checkmail(input) {
  var pattern1 = /^([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\@([A-Za-z0-9_\-\.])+\.([A-Za-z]{2,4})$/;
  if (pattern1.test(input)) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}

function proceed() {
  var name = document.getElementById("name");
  var email = document.getElementById("email");
  var phone = document.getElementById("phone");

  var movingfrom = document.getElementById("movingfrom");
  var movingto = document.getElementById("movingto");
  var date = document.getElementById("date");
  var msg = document.getElementById("message");
  var errors = "";

  if (name.value == "") {
    name.className = 'error';
    return false;
  } else if (email.value == "") {
    email.className = 'error';
    return false;
  } else if (checkmail(email.value) == false) {
    alert('Please provide a valid email address.');
    return false;
  } else if (phone.value == "") {
    phone.className = 'error';
    return false;
  } else if (movingfrom.value == "") {
    movingfrom.className = 'error';
    return false;
  } else if (movingto.value == "") {
    movingto.className = 'error';
    return false;
  } else if (date.value == "") {
    date.className = 'error';
    return false;
  } else if (msg.value == "") {
    msg.className = 'error';
    return false;
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "php/submit.php",
      data: $("#contact_form").serialize(),
      success: function(msg) {
        //alert(msg);
        if (msg) {
          $('#contact_form').fadeOut(1000);
          $('#contact_message').fadeIn(1000);
          document.getElementById("contact_message");
          return true;
        }
      }
    });
  }
};
```

```html
<div class="contact-form">

  <!-- Form  -->
  <div class="margin-top-50">
    <div class="contact-form">

      <!-- Success Msg -->
      <div id="contact_message" class="success-msg"> <i class="fa fa-paper-plane-o"></i>Thank You. Your Message has been Submitted</div>

      <!-- FORM -->
      <form id="contact_form" class="contact-form" method="post" action="php/submit.php" onsubmit="return ValidateForm()">
        <li class="col-sm-6">
          <label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name">
                        </label>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-6">
          <label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="email" id="email" placeholder="E-Mail">
                        </label>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-6">
          <label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="phone" id="phone" placeholder="Phone Number">
                        </label>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-6">
          <label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="movingfrom" id="movingfrom" placeholder="Moving From">
                        </label>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-6">
          <label>
                          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="movingto" id="movingto" placeholder="Moving To">
                        </label>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-6">
          <label>
                          <input type="date" class="form-control" name="date" id="date" placeholder="Date">
                        </label>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <label>
                    <select class="form-control" id="typeofmove" placeholder="Date Of Move" required>
                      <option>Move Type</option>
                        <option>Residential Move</option>
                      <option>Office Move</option>
                        <option>Inter-City Move</option>
                      <option>Piano Move</option>
                        <option>Spa-Pool Move</option>
                      <option>Pool Table Move</option>
                      <option>Loading & Unloading Only</option>
                      <option>Packing</option>
                        <option>Assembly</option>
                      <option>TradeMe Pickups</option>
                      <option>Commercial Delivery</option>
                      <option>Packaging Material</option>
                    </select>
                  </label>
        </li>
        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <label>
                          <textarea class="form-control" name="message" id="message" rows="5" placeholder="Your Message"></textarea>
                        </label>
        </li>

        <li class="col-sm-12">
          <button type="submit" value="submit" class="btn" id="btn_submit" onClick="proceed();">Submit</button>
        </li>
        </ul>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-4 col-sm-5 col-xs-12">

  SUBMIT.PHP /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
  <?php


// specify your email here

$to = 'testmail@gmail.com';



    // Assigning data from $_POST array to variables
    if (isset($_POST['name'])) { $name = $_POST['name']; }
 if (isset($_POST['phone'])) { $name = $_POST['phone']; }
    if (isset($_POST['email'])) { $from = $_POST['email']; }
 if (isset($_POST['movingfrom'])) { $name = $_POST['movingfrom']; }
 if (isset($_POST['movingto'])) { $name = $_POST['movingto']; }
 if (isset($_POST['date'])) { $name = $_POST['date']; }
 if (isset($_POST['typeofmove'])) { $name = $_POST['typeofmove']; }
   
    if (isset($_POST['message'])) { $message = $_POST['message']; }
    
    // Construct subject of the email
    $subject = 'Booking Enquiry ' . $name;

    // Construct email body
    $body_message .= 'Name: ' . $name . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Email: ' . $from . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Phone: ' . $phone . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Moving From: ' . $movingfrom . "\r\n";
        $body_message .= 'Moving To: ' . $movingto . "\r\n";
        $body_message .= 'Date Of Move: ' . $date . "\r\n";
    $body_message .= 'Message: ' . $message . "\r\n";

    // Construct headers of the message
    $headers = 'From: ' . $from . "\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Reply-To: ' . $from . "\r\n";

    $mail_sent = mail($to, $subject, $body_message, $headers);

    if ($mail_sent == true){ ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      window.alert("Sent Successfuly.");
    </script>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
      window.alert("Error! Please Try Again Later.");
    </script>
    <?php
    } // End else
    
?>
```

Comment: Does the file `php/submit.php` in your AJAX call exist? It looks like the PHP that is processing the form is in the same file as the form itself.

Comment: No the php is a different file in the PHP folder still not working

Comment: "not working" isn't an error message or a useful problem description. We can't do anything for you based on that. Please do some basic debugging to narrow down the issue. We're not a free debugging service, and we expect you to provide a [mre] of your issue, not just a big dump of all your code because you haven't done any standard investigation of it yet. See also [ask]. Thanks.

Comment: Hi I have now got it to a point where I do receive the message but it gets stuck on /php/submit.php at the end. Sorry am new to this.

Comment: In the PHP code, the assignment of variables is completely wrong. You are filling `$name` with the posted values of other fields and then reading `$phone` which asn't been filled before. Also, never expect POST data to be safe so you have to filter the values as they could contain malicious data, such as SQL injections, CSRF or XSS attacks. Typically, you have to validate that the phone number is a phone number. Checks in JavaScript is nice for the end user but not a protection for your backend. It has to be done in PHP for sure.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you can try check your url.Is it correct or no.For example send anything via ajax and show the response at console log.If it is not working thats mean your url is wrong.

Comment: Hi, This is not a specific answer for the question. You can prefer commenting instead of adding an answer.

Comment: Hi,because of reputations i cant for now